# Texture paint color is the wrong shade

Tags: texture-painting

I'm trying to make a carpet for a bedroom I'm making but when I got to paint it a color very close to white, it comes out dark gray. I set it to the right color in the color wheel and everything but it doesn't seem to be painting like that. Any help?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can't see your strength, is it on 1? Does it work when you change your blend type to `Add`

Comment: Changing the blend type to add did it! Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

So (full credit to [S. Visser](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/55667/s-visser) here) I went to where it said 'Blend' underneath the strength slider an then changed it to 'add'. Hope this helps!